# Carbon X1 - Internet Access lost when lid closed/opened

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

When my wife's brand new Carbon X1 7gen, has its lid opened, I find that the device is still connected to the WiFi but has no internet access. To get internet access I have to disconnect and reconnect the WiFi. As you can imagine my wife finds this really annoying. The lid only need to be closed a second and the machine is set to go to sleep immediately, so I doubt its a sleep issue.
Since there was an unrelated crash on Thursday evening (that reqd a complete OS reinstall), I've had the chance to prove all the drivers are up to date.

Operating System - Windows 10 - 1909
WiFi - Eero - eeroOS 3.19.0
Its difficult to tell:

- Is than Eero prblem - after the Lenovo connects to the wifi but doesn't get internet
- A Lenovo problem - since no other computer in the house suffers this problem?

Either way - its bizarre that Windows reports a connection to the Wifi but not internet.
Have you suffered this problem before and solved it?

Comment: I have an earlier X1 here with no issue. Go to Control Panel and run Lenovo System Update.  Update ALL drivers (especially wireless and power). Restart, update Windows (to V2004) and then final restart and test.

Comment: @John - thanks bizarrely that got tried the hard way. The laptop autoupdated to 2004 last week and still had the problem. On Thursday it crashed and wouldn't reboot. Having reinstalled the OS from scratch I updated all the drivers and the problem still exists.

Comment: I would definitely report this to Lenovo Support as there may be a hardware issue with the computer. I think this is your next step.

Answer (score 0):

In the end Lenovo support helped us with BIOS config option. I share it here, on the slight chance that anyone else ever suffers this again:

Continuously tap  F1 at boot (Lenovo Splash page) to enter the BIOS (may have to press Enter before F1 to open the interrupt page). Navigate to Config > Power > Sleep State > Set Sleep State to “Linux” instead of Windows. Press F10 to save and exit BIOS.

NOTE: Not all Models have this option in BIOS please.

So the problem was related to Windows - Modern Standby.